# How to get string value from a enum in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, class, enums

I have an enum of string values. I want to pass a string value to enum and get the value from it.

```
export enum OperationType  {
    CREATE = "CREATE",
    UPDATE = "UPDATE"
}
```

I have class as well

```
class Item {
type:string;
id:string
date:string
}
```

Now i am calling below function

```
function sendData(type:OperationType) {
//Do some work
}
```

Now i want to pass the value in enum like this but i am not able to do

```
//Here item.type = "CREATE"

sendData(OperationType[item.type])
```

But this is now allowed i get compile time error of wrong type. Please tell me how can i achieve?

EDIT:
Error is

**Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof OperationType'.**

Comment: You should change the type of `type` on your `Item` class to `OperationType`. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: But i can't becuase it has some more properties as well.

Comment: Well, on your `Item` class, you're defining `type` as a string. You can't change it ? If no, maybe another property is required.

Comment: What happens when if you try `sendData(OperationType[OperationType[item.type]])`?

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof OperationType'.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I'd use unions:

```
type OperationType = "CREATE" | "UPDATE";

class Item {
  type: OperationType;
  id: string;
  date: string;
}

function sendData(type: OperationType) {
  //Do some work
}
```

This approach provides same IDE intelligence and type checking. Otherwise, you can just change `type: OperationType;`.

Also you can use `const enums`. `const` modifier makes enum readonly and tells compiler not to generate reverse mapping;

```
export const enum OperationType  {
    CREATE = "CREATE",
    UPDATE = "UPDATE"
}
```

Comment: But i don't want to do this. Because this function is comman. I want to pass string value in enum and get OperationType so that only OperationType is passed as argument in function.

Comment: I am mapping Item class data to a webapi json response so item is always string from web api.

Comment: TypeScript itself doesn't provide runtime types. You can cast string to OperationType and it stops showing error. `sendData(item.type as OperationType)`

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong here is the type of the parameter inside the sendData fn definition.
That should be a string. You are telling ts that that is an Enum type, not the actual string.

so the fn definition should look like this:

```
function sendData(type: String) {
//Do some work
}
```

Comment: But i don't want to do this. Because this function is comman. I want to pass string value in enum and get OperationType so that only OperationType is passed as argument in function.